# Server returned 'request expired' less than 0 seconds after request was issued, but it shouldn't have expired for at least 600 seconds

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, replication, vmware-vcenter

When I click save & restart VMWare Replication Appliance VRM service:

Getting this error
Error applying startup configuration: Server returned 'request expired' less than 0 seconds after request was issued, but it shouldn't have expired for at least 600 seconds.

https://vrm.vmware.domain.local:5480/service/hms/cgi/health.py
gives green in XML

```
LookupService Address: vcenter.vmware.domain.local (and it's pingable from ssh @ vrm.vmware.domain.loca, DNS is set in networkingl)
SSO Admin: Administrator@vmware.domain.local (Such SSO domain exists in vcenter and I can login in vcenter web UI with vmware.domain.local\Administrator)
VRM Host: vrm.vmware.domain.local (also pinged from multiple hosts)
VRM Site Name: VRM NPB
vcenter Server Address: vcenter.vmware.domain.local
vcenter server port: 80
```

If I click Start VRM Service, it gets into

```
VRM service is started and quickly reverts to
VRM service is stopped
```

Installation of vcenter6 and vsphere replication appliance is done from ISOs (appliances, latest downloaded from VMWare 2 days ago)

vcenter complains on HMS service:
Failed to request health status from https://vrm.vmware.domain.local:5480/service/hms/cgi/health.py

**(however in my browser I can easily open this URL, yet the certs are self signed)**

What can be done?

I even debugged the script the VRM UI sends
http GET https://vrm.vmware.domain.local:5480/service/hms/cgi/hms.py?cmd=checklscert&ls=vcenter.vmware.domain.local&lsthumbpr…

```
{
   "result":{
      "vc":{
         "uuid":"56d6e005-2229-4bc6-99e9-7969c8883efd",
         "notBefore":"26 Jun 2015 12:56:47 GMT",
         "notAfter":"20 Jun 2025 12:56:47 GMT",
         "valid":"Certificate validation error",
         "thumbprint":"8D:E6:70:13:D2:4A:2D:D6:D7:27:21:C3:FA:36:48:56:F3:EA:91:EA",
         "subject":{
            "C":"US",
            "CN":"vcenter.vmware.domain.local",
            "L":"Unknown",
            "O":"Unknown",
            "ST":"Unknown",
            "OU":"Unknown"
         },
         "issuer":{
            "C":"US",
            "CN":"CA",
            "DC":"vmware",
            "L":"Unknown",
            "O":"vcenter.vmware.domain.local",
            "ST":"Unknown",
            "OU":"Unknown"
         }
      },
      "result":"ok",
      "ls":{
         "notBefore":"26 Jun 2015 12:56:47 GMT",
         "notAfter":"20 Jun 2025 12:56:47 GMT",
         "valid":"true",
         "thumbprint":"8D:E6:70:13:D2:4A:2D:D6:D7:27:21:C3:FA:36:48:56:F3:EA:91:EA",
         "subject":{
            "C":"US",
            "CN":"vcenter.vmware.domain.local",
            "L":"Unknown",
            "O":"Unknown",
            "ST":"Unknown",
            "OU":"Unknown"
         },
         "issuer":{
            "C":"US",
            "CN":"CA",
            "DC":"vmware",
            "L":"Unknown",
            "O":"vcenter.vmware.domain.local",
            "ST":"Unknown",
            "OU":"Unknown"
         }
      }
   },
   "error":null
}
```

If I'm trying to unregister the appliance I get this error: The appliance has to be configured correctly for unregister to work.

Comment: Maybe a call to VMware is in order...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution to fix this is to sync all parties (ESXi hosts, vcenter, VRM Appliance) with ntp servers. Once this done - the error is gone.